# Prefix wildcard with Simple Query String Query

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to use a prefix wildcard query, where `*ing` would find `frustrating`, with a Simple Query String Query?

It seems to be possible with the `allow_leading_wildcard` parameter (defaults to `true`) for the [Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html), but there's no mention of the prefix wildcard in the [Simple Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html), and prefix wildcard queries don't seem to work it it when I tried.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem https://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to allow `wildcard` search via `Simple Query String Query` you can create one of your own using `edge_ngram` tokenizer.

[Edge Ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html)

Example:

**Mappings**

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "min_gram": "2",
          "type": "ngram",
          "max_gram": "3"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "data": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index a document**

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "data": "frustrating"
}
```

**Search Query**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
 "query": {
   "simple_query_string": {
     "query": "ing",
     "fields": ["data"]
   }
 }
}
```

**Results**

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : 0.8630463,
    "_source" : {
      "data" : "frustrating"
    }
  }
]
```

Another solution is to use `query_string` (`allow_leading_wildcard` defaults to true) and you don't need the analyzer field in your mappings:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
 "query": {
   "query_string": {
     "query": "*ing",
     "fields": ["data"]
   }
 }
}
```

Hope this helps